# w2ui overlay is not rendered in cypress headless test

Tags: list, testing, headless, cypress, w2ui

#### Test passes in headed mode, but always fails in headless mode

I am trying to perform a test on the w2ui field of type "list"

Ideally, when we click on this w2ui list element, a drop-down (overlay) is generated with the select options and then we select an option.

But while running the test in headless mode, this drop-down is not generated.

**Code To reproduce the issue:-**

**Code for the webpage:**

[Link to HTML code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXGPoG)

Save the code provided in the above link in the file "test_webpage.html". Place this HTML file in the directory where cypress.json is located.

**Code of Cypress Test:**

```
describe('W2UI List Test', function() {
      it('Click List Field', function() {
        cy.visit('test_webpage.html');
        cy.get('.w2ui-select').siblings('.w2ui-field-helper').should('be.visible').click();
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.get('#w2ui-overlay tr[index=0]').should('be.visible').click();
    });
});
```

[Test Fail ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX1Ns.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a bug in Cypress currently where certain mouse events are not properly simulated when the Test Runner window is **not the active window**. This is being worked on here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1909#issuecomment-395995180 , This is being worked on

In the meantime, you can change your test code to this, for example:

```
cy.get('.w2ui-select').siblings('.w2ui-field-helper').click()
cy.contains('Barack Obama').click()
```

`Cypress`automatically checks for [`actionability`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Actionability) before clicking, so no need for `should('be.visible')`

Comment: Yes. Test do passes by changing the code to 

`cy.get('.w2ui-select').siblings('.w2ui-field-helper').click()
cy.contains('Barack Obama').click()`

But the element ("Barack Obama" in this case) is not actually selected.
You can check it out by taking screen shot before and after clicking.

`cy.get('.w2ui-select').siblings('.w2ui-field-helper').click();
cy.screenshot('before');
cy.contains('Barack Obama').click();
cy.screenshot('after');`